# Push notification doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, service-worker

I've created a simple web app notification (using a tutorial) to test out push notifications using Notification API, but it doesn't work on my Android phone (the notification permission is granted on the Phone), I am using Android 8.0 and Chrome 77.
Here's a link: https://www.niclamarino.com/prove.php
I am not an Android developer so I am pretty confused, is there anything I am missing out? Thanks!

My code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notification API</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Notification API</h1>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>

        if( 'Notification' in window){

            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                doNotify();
            }else{
                Notification.requestPermission()
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if( Notification.permission == 'granted'){ 
                            doNotify();
                        }
                    })
                    .catch( (err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }

        }

        function doNotify(){
            let title = "The Title";
            let t = Date.now() + 120000; // 2 mins in future
            let options = {
                body: 'Hello from JavaScript!',
                data: {prop1:123, prop2:"Nicla"},
                lang: 'en-NY',
                icon: 'http://educazionetecnica.dantect.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/STAR-icon.png',
                timestamp: t,
                vibrate: [100, 200, 100]
            }
            let n = new Notification(title, options);
            setTimeout( n.close.bind(n), 3000); //close notification after 3 seconds
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In order to help you we need to see your code. You can learn more about push notifications here -> https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications. to understand why you code is not working.

Comment: I have updated my question